# jhipster error in windows

Tags: jhipster

I was able to run the steps in the [this](http://www.jhipster.tech/development/#working-with-angular) link in Mac

When I tried the same example in Windows , I get the below error on npm start.

```
 [at-loader] Ok, 0.216 sec.
    Error: spawn UNKNOWN
        at _errnoException (util.js:999:13)
        at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:340:11)
        at exports.spawn (child_process.js:499:9)
        at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:209:15)
        at Object.module.exports.fileCommand (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhispter\node_modules\node-notifier\lib\utils.js:53:13)
        at WindowsToaster.notify (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhispter\node_modules\node-notifier\notifiers\toaster.js:65:9)
        at module.exports.WebpackNotifierPlugin.compilationDone (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhispter\node_modules\webpack-notifier\index.js:62:18)
        at Compiler.applyPlugins (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhispter\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:61:14)
        at Watching._done (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhispter\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:105:17)
        at onCompiled (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhispter\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:55:18)
        at applyPluginsAsync.err (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhispter\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:510:14)
        at next (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhispter\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:202:11)
        at D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhispter\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\instance.ts:488:25
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
    [Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:9060
    [Browsersync] Access URLs:
     -------------------------------------
           Local: http://localhost:9000
        External: http://10.23.150.12:9000
     -------------------------------------
              UI: http://localhost:3001
     UI External: http://10.23.150.12:3001
     -------------------------------------
    webpack: wait until bundle finished: /
    webpack: wait until bundle finished: /
    webpack: wait until bundle finished: /
    webpack: wait until bundle finished: /
    webpack: wait until bundle finished: /
```

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Node version 9.3.0
- NPM  version 5.6.0
- JHipster version 4.13.0

---

Installed node LTS version and got the same error again

```
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
        at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
        at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
        at exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
        at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:212:15)
        at Object.module.exports.fileCommand (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\node-notifier\lib\utils.js:53:13)
        at WindowsToaster.notify (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\node-notifier\notifiers\toaster.js:65:9)
        at module.exports.WebpackNotifierPlugin.compilationDone (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\webpack-notifier\index.js:62:18)
        at Compiler.applyPlugins (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:61:14)
        at Watching._done (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:105:17)
        at compiler.emitRecords.err (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:79:19)
        at Compiler.emitRecords (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:371:38)
        at compiler.emitAssets.err (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:62:20)
        at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:364:12)
        at next (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:218:11)
        at Compiler.compiler.plugin (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\webpack\lib\performance\SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
        at next (D:\Users\myusername\Projects\apps\testjhipsterlts\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:220:14)
```

- Windows 10 Enterprise Edition
- Node   8.9.3
- npm    5.6.0
- JHipster 4.13.0

---

Tried installing yarn and using it instead of npm - no luck. I still get the same error

Comment: updated the question with versions. Yes it hangs stating "wait until bundle is finished" and application is not accessible in 9000 / 9060 ports

Comment: ok. I will try the example after installing the LTS version . I used cmd window in windows .

Comment: Same error with Node LTS version as well

Comment: I am doing this in a new project and folder after installing the LTS version

Comment: I saw you use npm rather than yarn, does it mean that you generated your project using --npm command line option? Because otherwise the default is yarn. BTW, it works fine for me with same versions.

Comment: Can you check value of "clientPackageManager" in your .yo-rc.json?

Comment: I am using npm instead of yarn. .yo-rc.json entry "clientPackageManager": "npm",

Comment: Just generated an app with --npm and then ran npm start. Works the same except slower than yarn. So it looks like a specific issue in your env, sorry I can't help.

Comment: Thanks for your time and support.  I will check if I can  make it working.